# How are tensors added in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to understand some basics about tensorflow by reading this tutorial here: https://www.guru99.com/tensor-tensorflow.html
What I cannot understand is why when running these commands:

```
# Add
tensor_a = tf.constant([[1,2]], dtype = tf.int32)
tensor_b = tf.constant([[3, 4]], dtype = tf.int32)
tensor_add = tf.add(tensor_a, tensor_b)
print(tensor_add)
```

I get this result:

```
Tensor("Add:0", shape=(1, 2), dtype=int32)
```

I did the calculation on paper and when adding these 2 vectors, I get something complete different(4,6), why is that? What is a "tensor" anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "tensor" in TensorFlow is a computational object. What you get with `tf.add` is a NODE that adds its inputs, `tensor_a` and `tensor_b` - which is what you're seeing with `Tensor("Add:0")` (the `:0` is its form of 'id'). This node, however, does nothing until *executed* - it's just "there" (see below). To execute, run

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:       # 'with' ensures computing resources are 
    print(sess.run(tensor_add))  # properly handled, but isn't required
```

I suggest you check out some starter tutorials, as TF isn't exactly intuitive - e.g. [here](https://easy-tensorflow.com/tf-tutorials/basics/graph-and-session). Good luck

[image]